# Cannot invoke 'performOperation' with an argument list of type '(NSAttributedString)'

Tags: swift

```
@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
    if userIsInTheMiddleTypeANumber {
        enter()
    }

    if let  operation = sender.currentAttributedTitle {
        if let result = brain.performOperation(operation){
            displayValue = result
        } else {
            displayValue = 0
        }
    }

}
```

`brain.performOperation` error is

> Cannot invoke 'performOperation' with an argument list of type
>   '(NSAttributedString)'

```
 func evaluate() -> Double? {
    let (result, _) = evaluate(opStack)
    return result
}

 func performOperation(symbol: String) -> Double? {
    if let operation = knownOps[symbol] {
        opStack.append(operation)
    }
    return evaluate()
}
```

This is the content of Stanford 's white-bearded teacher Lesson,Why Stackoverflow To force the user to enter more text , it is very unreasonable

Comment: thanks you,I know they are two different types,but i have code                                 var displayValue: Double{
        get{
            return  NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set{
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
    }

Comment: var displayValue: Double{
        get{
            return  NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set{
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `NSAttributedString` to `String` because your function accept only `String` argument.

This way you can convert `NSAttributedString` to `String` :

```
if let result = brain.performOperation(operation.string)
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: yes , grammar is true,but run in the program,error,                                                     self Calculatoer.ViewController 0x00007fda2a5219f0 0x00007fda2a5219f0

Comment: var displayValue: Double{
        get{
            return  NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set{
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
    }

Comment: var displayValue: Double{
        get{
            return  NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set{
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
    }